# Love2d- attempt to index field 'filesystem' (a nil value)

Tags: file, indexing, lua, null

Whenever I try to open my program I get the error.   Attempt to index field 'filesystem' (a nil value) does anyone know what could be causing this problem? help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Love2d has no global `filesystem` object that I'm aware of. You want `love.filesystem`.

Comment: Ya I have love.filesystem.load

Comment: So... are you sure you're running your script via Love2d, and not Lua by accident? You didn't provide a whole lot of context in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not excluding the module from the conf.lua file. If you are, either enable the module or use `include "love.filesystem"`

Make sure you use love.filesystem, love2d doesn't define a `filesystem` value.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're not excluding any related modules from conf.lua. I had the same problem with love.audio. It turned out that I was excluding love.sound in conf.lua! 
¬_¬ Caused me no end of headache.

Derp!

EDIT: Also, check that you're not using incorrect syntax from an outdated version of Love2D.
That can be checked [here](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.filesystem).